# External Storage

Tags: external-sd

I have a Kyocera Hydro. I need help with external storage. My SD Card slot is broken but I wish to use the camera, gallery, and download apps. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Your phone should have enough internal storage space for a couple of pictures and a couple of apps. To be honest, if it is an old phone your best bet is to just buy a new one (they are pretty cheap these days if you get them with a new contract). If the phone is new it should be covered under warranty as a hardware defect. You should check with your carrier / insurance to see if it is covered.